# Button function pause strangely when opening another window

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
from tkinter import *


class MyClass:
    def return_value(self):
        self.value = 5
        self.window2.destroy()

    def my_window(self, parent):
        self.value = 10
        self.window2 = Toplevel(parent)

        Button(self.window2, text="text2", command=self.return_value).pack()

        self.window2.mainloop()
        return self.value

the_class = MyClass()

def button():
    if the_class.my_window(window) == 10:
        print("10")
    else:
        print("5")

window = Tk()
Button(window,text="text",command=button).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

If you run this the print will only be called after all the windows are closed and not when the secondary one is. I have looked into using wait_window() but didn't see how I could apply it to my code

Edit: I have tried to implement update() unsuccessfully and would be grateful for an example

Comment: You should not be calling `mainloop` twice. A proper tkinter program only ever calls it exactly once.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how it would work with it being called once?